# Civilization IV: How can I tell what version I have?

Tags: technical-issues, civilization-4

How can I tell what version I have of Civilization IV? I purchased it in Steam.

In Steam I can click on `Properties` -> `Local Files` and see "Current content BuildID: 494450". Is this enough? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unsure if the Steam BuildID is useful for determining version. Instead, from the main menu (in-game) select **Advanced**, and then **About this Build**.

[image]

Comment: Can't believe I didn't look there. It was a late night. Thanks!

Comment: Strangely, if I install both the normal version and the `Original Release – UNSUPPORTED` beta version on Windows, they both show the same version number of 1.7.4. Perhaps Steam is swapping out some of the data files behind the scenes but there is a version-tracking file that remains untouched.